# Missing Member Exception when Using Acrobat JSObject 3D calls

Tags: vb.net, acrobat

I am busy trying to write a basic application in vb.net to select a specific node in a 3D PDF using acrobats 3D API. I am viewing the 3D PDF in a form using this code:

Dim avdoc As Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc
        Dim pddoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
        Dim jso As Object
        Dim a3d As Object

```
    avdoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    avdoc.OpenInWindowEx("C:\Users\Marcel\Documents\TFC Test\3C555-01-01.pdf", Me.Handle.ToInt32, 1, True, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

    pddoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc()

    jso = pddoc.GetJSObject

    a3d = jso.getAnnot3D(0, "3D Annot 0")

    a3d.activated = True

    MsgBox(a3d.context3D.scene.meshes.count)

    a3d.context3D.scene.selectednode = a3d.context3D.scene.meshes.getByIndex(0)
```

When executing this code the count of meshes (24) displays properly, but the line to select the node gives the following error:

'Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))'

From some further inspection it appears that I can access any of the properties of the 3D objects but cannot access their functions.

I have looked around but can't seem to find any info on this. Does anyone know how to resolve this or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use "selectedNode"... capital N.

The main document JavaScript engine and the one in the 3D annotation are different. I doubt the 3D JavaScript API is as forgiving about capitalization through the JSO as the Acrobat JavaScript is.

Comment: Thanks. That helps but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I get that error even if I just use the code: 

a3d.context3D.scene.meshes.getByIndex(0)

Comment: In your question, you said that the count was showing correctly. Is that the case or not?

Comment: Yes. The count works fine. Any of the 3D properties seem to work fine, it is just the function which give that error.